# Definition of the derivative for a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}
^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ given by $$f(x, y) = x
^2 − y
^2$$

For one variable you can use the definition of the derivative to show $ f $ is differentiable by using

$$\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\|f{(x + h)} - f{(x)}-f'(x)\|}{\|h\|}}=0$$
How do you apply the  definition of the derivative to show $ f $ is differentiable for a function containing two variables such as the function above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $f\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ is differentiable at ${\bf p} \in \Bbb R^n$ if there is a linear map ${\sf D}f({\bf p}) \in {\rm Lin}(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^k)$ such that $$\lim_{{\bf h} \to 0} \frac{f({\bf p}+{\bf h})-f({\bf p}) -{\sf D}f({\bf p})({\bf h})}{\|{\bf h}\|} = 0.$$This is called the total derivative of $f$ at ${\bf p}$. If that map exists, it is unique. Its matrix in the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^k$ is the Jacobian matrix you should have learnt in a first multivariable calculus course. If $k=1$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the standard inner product, ${\sf D}f({\bf p})$ is identified with the gradient vector $\nabla f({\bf p})$ via ${\sf D}f({\bf p})({\bf v}) = \langle \nabla f({\bf p}),{\bf v}\rangle$. In your case, ${\sf D}f(x,y)\colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is a linear functional given by $${\sf D}f(x,y)(h,k) = 2xh - 2yk.$$So you have to check that $$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{(x+h)^2 - (y+k)^2 - x^2 + y^2 - 2xh+2yk}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = 0,$$which you should be able to do. For more details see, e.g., Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds or Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

You can "apply the definition of the derivative" to prove this:

> > If $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are both continuous then $f$ is differentiable.

That's not too hard, should be in any decent "advanced calculus" book. But there really is something to be proved here! Let $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,&(xy=0),\\1,&(xy\ne0).\end{cases}$$Then $\partial f\partial x(0,0)=\partial f/\partial y(0,0)=0$, although $f$ is certainly not differentiable at the origin, since it's not even continuous at the origin.